# Sentry vs MANAGERS and ADMINS in Django, what's the correct setup?

Tags: django, sentry

I'm using [Sentry](https://sentry.io) to collect exceptions from my Django application. Recently I learned about the [ADMINS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-ADMINS) and [MANAGERS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-MANAGERS) setting for Django, so, I added them to my `settings.py`. I don't want to miss anything going wrong in my server.

Adding them had an unintended consequence, as far as I can see: some exceptions go to Sentry, but some go to the admins (or managers*). To get those exceptions back in Sentry, I need to make `ADMINS` blank again. Is this the correct setup? Are there any notifications I would lose by having `ADMINS` blank? Is it possible to set `ADMINS` and have Sentry still be used to report all notifications?

I'm using sentry-sdk version 0.7.9 which I believe is the latest one at the time of this writing.

This is my logging config (requested by ptr):

```
# Set up logging that is Heroku-friendly, based on:
# https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku/blob/master/django_heroku/core.py#L117-L148
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "verbose": {
            "format": ("%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d [%(process)d] [%(levelname)s] " +
                       "pathname=%(pathname)s lineno=%(lineno)s " +
                       "funcname=%(funcName)s %(message)s"),
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
        },
        "simple": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d [%(levelname)s] %(message)s",
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "null": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "logging.NullHandler",
        },
        "console": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "verbose"
        },
        "simple_console": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "simple"
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        "testlogger": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "level": "DEBUG",
        }
    }
}
```

* I'm not sure because I set them to the same value.

Comment: Could you post the logging config from your settings, if you have one? It sounds like `AdminEmailHandler` isn't propogating the errors

Comment: @ptr: I added it to the question. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Are you using `raven` or `sentry_sdk`, and which version? I think `sentry_sdk` should be above any logging config and should just work better in general.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer I'm using sentry_sdk and version 0.7.9. I also added this to the question.

Comment: At this point it would become a bug (or feature request, not sure) for sentry-python, and I think this is better kept track of in https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python

Comment: This is now submitted as a bug: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/issues/356

Comment: @pupeno can we have a follow-up on this one?